# Is this train cancelled or not?

Tags: uk, trains

I see two conflicting information on my itinerary, on Trainline UK, one saying that train is cancelled and one saying "on time".

[image]

I'm supposed to change on Swindon and head over to Bristol Temple Meads. However, the itinerary says that the train starting from London Paddington is cancelled, while the Swindon train says "on time".

This is rather confusing, especially because on top of the ticket it says Train Cancelled:

[image]

Does anyone know if my journey will be unaffected? My guess is that the train from London Paddington is cancelled but the train does run as per normal on Swindon...

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What date is this for?

Comment: this train is for today.

Comment: It means the train is starting from a different station (Swindon - Bristol rather than London - Bristol).

Comment: @niemiro Actually, it's only "cancelled" at Paddington and is running from Reading to Bristol.

Answer (score 15):

I'm making the assumption here that this is for today.

The 1804 train is [cancelled](https://www.realtimetrains.co.uk/train/W30501/2021-05-14/detailed) (see "Cancelled from WTT today 14th May 2021 only" on the left). Unfortunately GWR have had serious issues with their fleet this past week, and while some trains are now back in service, many services are still altered or cancelled as they still have significantly fewer trains in service than normal. I'm not sure why the 1804 is not showing as cancelled on Trainline.

However, there is a [replacement service](https://www.realtimetrains.co.uk/train/26064/2021-05-14) leaving Didcot at 1808 which arrives at Swindon at 1826.

From there, this connects onto the [1845 CrossCountry](https://www.realtimetrains.co.uk/train/26035/2021-05-14#allox_id=0) shuttle service to Bristol Temple Meads. This arrives at Bristol at 1928.

However, in practice you will likely to be able to make the [1829 GWR shuttle service](https://www.realtimetrains.co.uk/train/W30313/2021-05-14) to Bristol Temple Meads, even though this is not a valid connection officially (minimum connection time is 5 minutes at Swindon). If you can make the connection though there's no reason you shouldn't. The connection is across the platform so you don't have to use the subway, be towards the rear of the train for an easy nip across to the train awaiting in the adjacent platform at Swindon. This service was originally the 1828 from Swindon (1730 from Paddington) but has been altered and retimed slightly to start from Swindon. This sort of explains what you see in The Trainline, though I don't know why the 1804 isn't showing as cancelled.

Because of all the disruption your tickets will be accepted on these alternative services.

(If you're curious, I suspect the weird display in The Trainline app is caused by the train being cancelled in the timetabling system (via a VSTP entry) but not in the real-time running system (TRUST). I suspect with all the last-minute alterations this was missed in error).

EDIT: I just realised I was looking at a different train. Nevertheless my point still stands as this other cancelled train was also part of your itinerary. The train in question was technically not cancelled; it was altered to start from Swindon and re-timed slightly (it's the 1829 service linked above). But the point is moot when the connecting train is actually cancelled...

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response! I'll look into it more closely later, wish me luck 

Comment: @FinnLim good luck! If you arrive at your final destination 15 minutes or more later than in the itinerary in place when you bought your ticket, you should be eligible for Delay Repay (though getting operators to pay out in these circumstances with widespread disruption/emergency timetables can sometimes be tricky).

Comment: I believe the train which is "Cancelled" at Paddington actually starts from Reading -- that is, the service *into* London was running so late that it terminated at Reading in order that the outbound journey could run on time at least from there.

Comment: update: i got to the destination by 19:09 :) thanks for the help! turns out that there were connecting trains that were announced on each station

Comment: @AndrewLeach right effect, wrong reason - they were running their few fast trains as shuttles, and relying on other services to get people to Reading and other  interchange stations.  GWR's information delivery has been really bad (I commute daily on their long-distance services) for example releasing the timetables for the next day at midnight, so I'm not surprised this was unclear.